# Cannot change zsh prompt

Tags: 11.10, zsh

For some reason I can't change my zsh prompt by typing, say, `PS1="%#"`. I'm using the admin-suggested config on Ubuntu 11.10. Am I doing it wrong or is it a bug?

Here's the content of my ~/.zshrc:

```
# Set up the prompt

autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit
prompt adam1
#PS1="`echo "$PS1" | tr Kk Ff`"
#PS2="`echo "$PS2" | tr Kk Ff`"
#PS3="`echo "$PS3" | tr Kk Ff`"
#PS4="`echo "$PS4" | tr Kk Ff`"

setopt histignorealldups sharehistory

# Use emacs keybindings even if our EDITOR is set to vi
bindkey -e

# Keep 1000 lines of history within the shell and save it to ~/.zsh_history:
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history

# Use modern completion system
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' auto-description 'specify: %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt %SAt %p: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert%s
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=long
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose true

zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=0=01;31'
zstyle ':completion:*:kill:*' command 'ps -u $USER -o pid,%cpu,tty,cputime,cmd'
```

Comment: Please post the syntax you are using to set your prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prompt theme resets `PS1` in the [`precmd` hook](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions), specifically through an entry in `precmd_functions`. If you want to set your own prompt, don't use prompt themes at all: comment out the two lines about `promptinit` and the `prompt adam1` line below them. If you want to use prompt themes, use their own customization capabilities. You'll have better luck with a prompt theme if you want something very fancy and one of the preexisting themes suits you, and better luck setting your own if you want a simple or highly customized prompt.

Comment: I'm trying to set up my own hook with `precmd_functions += color_fix_precmd` right after setting up the prompt, but zsh fails to recognize precmd. What am I doing wrong? UPD: nvm, I removed spaces and it worked.