# WSL zsh Shell Prompt Not Updating

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zsh

Im running Ubuntu 22.04 under WSL and would like to change my prompt info and look from the default.

I did the following

```bash
sudo apt install zsh
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

I updated the .zshrc file to be `PROMPT='%n@%m %1~ %#'` but when I output $PROMPT it shows me the old value `%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{cyan}%(4~|...|)%3~%F{white} %# %b%f%k`

is there another file I need to be updating or am I doing something incorrect ?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/90661/178692

Comment: I did that but still the same problem. Are there other places that prompt value could be hiding ? Its as if any changes I make to the .zshrc file dont persist. I see my desired prompt value in .zshrc but echo $PROMPT & what is actually displayed are still the old value

Comment: sorry that's the limit of my knowledge :(

Comment: Are you using any `zsh` extensions? Can you [edit] your question to include the content of your `~/.zshrc` file?